# owl:topDataProperty under Data Property in Protege

Tags: owl, protege

I'm not sure if this is a bug or something broken with my Protege but when I'm adding new value to a data property in Protege, suddenly an owl:topDataProperty will be under one of my data property as shown below.

[image: protege 5.0]

Is it something wrong with my Protege or my ontology structure?

Comment: Is reasoning enabled?

Comment: @AKSW yes it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your property is inferred to be equivalent to `owl:topDataProperty` - and so it is both a superproperty and a subproperty of your property. We can't tell from this screenshot though, it's necessary to see the rest of the ontology.

Comment: but when I want to edit the value of the data property, there is no more `owl:topDataProperty` under `imgSize` which is so weird. And currently my ontology is inconsistent as said by the reasoner. Can this be one of the reason?

Comment: Yes - inconsistent ontologies cannot be used for reasoning, therefore inferences might disappear.

Comment: Thank you.
I think I have found the solution.
As you said, it is because of inconsistent ontology. Finally found out where the problem is.